# Should this question be closed? Consider reopening

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

My question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133782/github-workflow-for-solo-developer) was closed as a duplicate. However, I feel strongly that the close is inaccurate. The linked question doesn't answer my question in the slightest.

My question is "what is the best approach" where the supposed duplicate is "are there benefits"

Already know many of the benefits, I'm trying to best implement them.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple possible choices to close with, duplicate seemed the easiest. There is also [As a sole developer (for now), how should I be using Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114258/as-a-sole-developer-for-now-how-should-i-be-using-git) which might help you best.

You're asking a few different questions rolled into one. How to relate git to svn, what is a good branch / commit / merge workflow for a single developer, how “master” works or should work in a repo. You need to edit the question to make one of these the main point, and then check to see if it isn't answered by one of the many other git related questions. I've listed a few here I think can be helpful.

1. [git in non-distributed, independent, lone programming ...best practice(s)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46039/git-in-non-distributed-independent-lone-programming-best-practices)
2. [What should be the workflow with a git repository?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89025/what-should-be-the-workflow-with-a-git-repository)
3. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-development-with-git

Comment: Is there a way to list all the duplicates you mentioned in the closed question? The one suggested there now indeed looks like a mismatch to me, pretty confusing

Comment: @gnat - while the duplicate link is auto generated it is actually inserted into the question body so can be edited. It should always remain, but there's nothing to stop you (or anyone else) editing extra links into the list or indeed replacing the current one with a more appropriate one.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks for advice - the list has been edited in [rev 7 of the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/133782/7)